# Issue when using Galleria theme with ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, themes, galleria

I am trying to use the galleria photo gallery.

Issue: The theme loading code

`Galleria.loadTheme('/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');` works fine only when we are using it in the default action of home controller i.e. Home/Index

I was using the theme on a View called Display. so i wrote an action in Home to return Display view.

The images must be showing in the Galleria theme photo viewer, but they show up as images one after other instead.

If i try and call the display view from Index action, it works fine. but i want to do something else in the Index view.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme script does not seem to be loading. The cause can be a virtual path issue.

I´m used to use the Galleria plugin in this way:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/JQuery.Galleria/1.2.5/galleria-1.2.5.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var virtualPath = '@Url.Content("~/")';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        Galleria.loadTheme(virtualPath + '/Scripts/jQuery.Galleria/1.2.5/themes/twelve/galleria.twelve.min.js');

        // Initialize Galleria
        $('#galleria').galleria({ autoplay: false, /* true, miliseconds */
                                  thumbnails: true,  /*true, false, numbers, empty */
                                  imageCrop: true,  /*true, false, height, width */
                                  transition: "pulse",  /*fade, fadeslide, slide, flash, pulse */
                                  trasitionSpeed: 500,
                                  thumbFit: true

        });

    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.